# Сортировка элементов в ассоциативном массиве

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть такой массив (получаю данные из бд):

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [product_option_id] => 245
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 47
                            [option_value_id] => 131
                            [name] => 3
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 48
                            [option_value_id] => 132
                            [name] => 4
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 46
                            [option_value_id] => 130
                            [name] => 2
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 49
                            [option_value_id] => 133
                            [name] => 5
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 35
                            [option_value_id] => 120
                            [name] => 1
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                )

            [option_id] => 31
            [name] => Градус (Ax)
            [type] => select
            [value] => 
            [required] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_option_id] => 244
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 41
                            [option_value_id] => 141
                            [name] => 5
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 34
                            [option_value_id] => 119
                            [name] => 1
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 40
                            [option_value_id] => 140
                            [name] => 4
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 39
                            [option_value_id] => 139
                            [name] => 3
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 38
                            [option_value_id] => 138
                            [name] => 2
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                )

            [option_id] => 30
            [name] => Цилиндр (Сyl)
            [type] => select
            [value] => 
            [required] => 1
        )
```

Вопрос. как отсортировать элементы в `values` по его имени `name`. Тобишь что бы было в порядке возрастания:

Пример:

```
[values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 35
                            [option_value_id] => 120
                            [name] => 1
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 46
                            [option_value_id] => 130
                            [name] => 2
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 47
                            [option_value_id] => 131
                            [name] => 3
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 48
                            [option_value_id] => 132
                            [name] => 4
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 49
                            [option_value_id] => 133
                            [name] => 5
                            [image] => 
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sortedArray = usort($data['values'], function ($a, $b) {
    if($a['name'] > $b['name'])
        return 1;
    if($a['name'] < $b['name'])
        return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

Используется функция [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

Comment: Про `<=>` забыли?

Comment: Этот оператор с 7 версии. Не факт, что там используется 7.

Comment: стоит версия php 5

Comment: Возникла проблема. я использую opencart. я подготавливаю опции товара и их мне и нужно отсортировать. Это делается в контроллере. 
Я вставил ваш код и теперь у меня не работает страница товара (там где вызывается этот контроллер). что не так?

Comment: В логах нужно найти ошибку. Скорее всего пропущен какой-то символ, или совсем старый PHP, тогда ща напишу дополнительный код.

Comment: Извиняюсь, затупил, обновил код. Там нужно название у анонимной функции убрать.

Comment: Большое спасибо! получилось!